# Multiple openfile prompt

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I am writing a windows form application program,where I have multiple file opening buttons, & I donot want to write same openfile dialogue so many times. So, I have used code to trace out which button raised the openfile_click event. My code is as below:-

```
    private void SelectFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
        if (sender == Fbutton1)
        {
            FtextBox1.Text = ofd.FileName;
            ofd.Dispose();
        }

        else if (sender == Fbutton2)
        {
            FtextBox2.Text = ofd.FileName;
            ofd.Dispose();
        }
        else if (sender == Tbutton1)
        {
            TtextBox1.Text = ofd.FileName;
            ofd.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            ofd.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Every thing is running is allright, I can choose file as per my choise, but after I have selected 3-4 files one after other, the openfile dialog prompts 2-3 times on a single click on the file opening button, even if I click OK or cancel or red cross button on the top-right corner of dialogbox.I just can not understand, what is firing up this dialogbox multiple time on a single click event.
  Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: There is nothing in the provided code suggesting that it will show `ofd` more than one time. Please provide [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The most probable reason for this behaviour is that you register/call this event more than one time. Also, take a look into [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to simplify the disposal of `ofd`.

Comment: Thank you Eugene Podskal, I am giving you the entire form2.cs file, that holds the above code snippet, Please help me to trace out the error & rectify it.

Comment: "entire form2.cs file" may not exactly be the thing meant by [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I assure you Eugene, it (form2.cs) is :) , excluding some casual string resources. Please, please have a look at my updated code.

Comment: The code is big so I'm adfing them as my own answer. :)